# Find a unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{T}AU$ has the form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Consider a matrix $A:$ $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 3 &1 &1\\-1 &7 &-1\\0 &0 &5 \end{bmatrix}$$.
Find a unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{T}AU$ has the form $$\begin{bmatrix} * &* &*\\0 &* &*\\0 &* &* \end{bmatrix}$$.

I wanted to use Schur decomposition but realized the matrix may not be upper triangular. I think I need to apply Gram-Schmidt but the eigenvalues of $A$ are messy. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, this process is a piece of the proof of Schur decomposition

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. By the way, can you star from here to explain how we can find the Schur decomposition of $A$? (without computation, of course)

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919088/schur-decomposition-to-show-matrix-has-n-orthonormal-eigenvectors/1919122#1919122)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: take a normalized eigenvector $u_1$, i.e. $Au_1=\lambda u_1$, and complete it to an ON-base by $u_2$, $u_3$. Then $U=[u_1\ u_2\ u_3]$ is one choice of the matrix. It is easy to see that
$$
A[u_1\ u_2\ u_3]=[u_1\ u_2\ u_3]\begin{bmatrix}\lambda &*&*\\0&*&*\\0&*&*\end{bmatrix}.
$$

P.S. Without solving any characteristic equations, $\lambda=5$ seems to be the most obvious choice of an eigenvalue of $A$ with very easy $u_1$.

Comment: Note: one can extend $\{u_1\}$ into an orthonormal basis by applying the Gram Schmit process to $\{u_1,v_2,v_3\}$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So it means I still need to find the eigenvectors of the other eigenvalues, right?

Comment: @KhoaLe No! $v_2,v_3$ don't need to be eigenvectors, $\{u_1,v_2,v_3\}$ just needs to be linearly independent

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ok!

Comment: @KhoaLe No need, Gram Schmit can orthonormalize any base, not necessarily eigenvectors. Even easier, after you found $u_1=[1;1;1]/\sqrt{3}$ then do some easy choice of $u_2\bot u_1$, for example, $u_2=[1;-1;0]/\sqrt{2}$. The last one $u_3$ can you calculate as the vector product $u_1\times u_2$.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks! We chose the same $u_2$.

Comment: @A.G. Your method works nicely in 3 dimensions, but doesn't generalize